# Как устранить проблему Unable to start sub-process при использовании JavaGit?

Tags: git, java

Не могу понять в чем проблема с библиотекой JavaGit при выполнении команд. С чем это может быть связано? Как решить?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: 020100: Unable to start sub-process.
    atedu.nyu.cs.javagit.client.cli.ProcessUtilities.startProcess
                                                    (ProcessUtilities.java:50)
    at edu.nyu.cs.javagit.client.cli.ProcessUtilities.runCommand
                                                    (ProcessUtilities.java:141)
    at edu.nyu.cs.javagit.client.cli.CliGitStatus.status(CliGitStatus.java:82)
    at edu.nyu.cs.javagit.client.cli.CliGitStatus.status(CliGitStatus.java:121)
    at edu.nyu.cs.javagit.api.com7)
    at com.library.test.SideAppStartmands.GitStatus.status
                                    (GitStatus.java:14.main(SideAppStart.java:36)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Либа не может стартануть git. Проверьте, есть ли в переменной окружения `%PATH%` путь к git-у.

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего не запускается бинарник git'а - поищите в этом направлении.

Согласно докам, для Windows требуется msysgit или git под cygwin, что прямо скажем довольно таки экзотично :)

Comment: Я не прописал git path в системные переменные :-O

Comment: Я бы обратил внимание на то что JavaGit находится в глубокой бете - версия 0.1.0 - напрягает

Comment: А какие api лучше использовать?